# Why is the numerator of Baye's Theorem $P(A\cap B)$ instead of $P(A|B)$?

Tags: bayes-theorem

For example, say I have am holding an object; $O$ is the event that the object is an orange, and $R$ is the event that the object is round.

$P(O|R) = \frac{P(R|O)}{P(R)}$

This is obviously incorrect, but it reads to me like: "the probability that *the object is an orange given that it is round* is the probability of *an object being round given that it is an orange*, divided by the *probability that the object is round* in general". Which seems reasonable.

Why is the above interpretation wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Philosophically” it’s wrong because the right hand side is about roundness — the only place Orange appears is as a given condition — so not sure how you can get any info on Orange on LHS from only data about roundness on RHS.

Conceptually, it’s just wrong.

From the definition of conditional probability:

$$P(O|R)= \frac{P(O\cap R)}{P(R)}$$

However:

$$ \frac{P(R|O)}{P(R)}=  \frac{\frac{P(O\cap R)}{P(O)}}{P(R)}=\frac{P(R\cap O)}{P(R)P(O)}\neq P(O|R)$$

Comment: I understand that this may be vague, but is there an informal english way to explain why it's incorrect?

Comment: @EachOneChew — see my first paragraph. It’s not about why it’s mathematically wrong.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @EachOneChew If you understand what conditional probability is supposed to represent and draw a Venn diagram of this you’ll see you are doing something that has no sensible interpretation as a conditional probability